# setting up Alluxio cluster, path points to Java 8 but Alluxio thinks it's java 7?

Tags: alluxio

I am setting up an Alluxio cluster. I ran the script `./bin/alluxio-start.sh all SudoMount`, but got this error `Error: Alluxio requires Java 8 or Java 11, currently Java 1.7.0_321 found`. I already set JAVA_HOME and add it to $PATH to point to Java 8. Why does Alluxio still think it is java 7?

```
$$echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
…$ java -version
openjdk version “1.8.0_322”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this and see what’s the output: `sudo update-alternatives --display java`
if it’s linked to 1.7 then you can use following  command to set it to 1.8 `sudo update-alternatives --config java`